# question related to the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  I know that $f$ is $C^{1,1}$ and also that for each given $y \in [0,1]$ there exists $x_{y} \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_{y},y)=0$.  By the implicit function theorem I it follows that there exists open set $U$ containing $x_{y}$ and open set $V$ containing $y$ and a differentiable function $g:U \rightarrow V$ such that $f(x,g(x))=0$ for all $x \in U$.

I also know that as $y \uparrow 1$, $x_{y} \downarrow 0$ and as $y \downarrow 0$, $x_{y} \uparrow 1$.  Can I conclude that the differentiable function g is actually defined on all $[0,1]$?

Thanks!